# Signing android app with cert valid only for few years

Tags: java, android, google-apps-marketplace, code-signing-certificate

I have a signing certificate which is valid up to 2015.

Can I used this cert to sign android app as google has recommended to use certificate valid upto 25 years. I am planning to release app on google app store.

Will I get any problems with this cert?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just create another certificate with a longer validity period if you are concerned about the validity period?

Comment: yes you will get problems: In 2016 you won't be able to do updates anymore. Just create a certificate that is 1000 years valid.

Comment: thnx guys but certificate from valid CA. its costly stuff. I think you are getting me. Is there issue apart from update?

Answer (score 3):

From http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

> If you plan to publish your application(s) on Google Play, the key you
>   use to sign the application(s) must have a validity period ending
>   after 22 October 2033. Google Play enforces this requirement to ensure
>   that users can seamlessly upgrade applications when new versions are
>   available.

You will have problems, because Google Play would deny your apk.

Comment: thnx for clean answer.